# Play Framework: await-like functionality in Jobs

Tags: playframework, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a long-running task (without blocking the HTTP request execution pool) using the Asynchronous Jobs in Play.
Jobs in Play are fully managed by the framework so Play will take care of the database connections and transactions. This means that a job runs as a plain invocation within a single transaction. This is great for most use-cases but what if you need to commit some data before the job finishes?

Well, according to [Guillaume Bort](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/2c4661ccf0358c81), one option would be

> to split your process into several small jobs

He gives the following example:

```
@On("0 0 12 * * ?") 
public class UpdateCounters extends Job { 
   public void doJob() { 
       List<Employee> empList = Employee.find("long and boring SQL :)").fetch(); 
       for(Employee emp : empList) { 
           new UpdateEmployeeJob(emp).now().get(); 
       } 
   } 
}
```

This is cool... Each new job will have it's own transaction so when this new job finishes, it commits that data. Clean and simple!
But what if you don't want to do this asynchronous? Say you need to wait until the data is committed before you continue with the initial job?

Normally, you would retrieve the Promise from the new Job and call await(jobPromise) but this will not work in a Job (await is only available when extending Controller and is not implemented on Job)...

So what would be the best way to pause the initial job until the new smaller job completes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking into different ways of finding out if a Job was done (without using a database), I noticed that a Play Promise implements the [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface and thus has the isDone() operation which can be used this to check if the task completed.

Even better, the [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface also defines a get() method which

> waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

So pausing the initial job until the new smaller job completes, can be achieved by calling get() on the Promise, returned when calling now() on the smaller job (as indeed done in Guillaume's example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the following code to do batch commit:

```
        Employee.em().getTransaction().commit();
        Employee.em().getTransaction().begin();
        Employee.em().flush();
        Employee.em().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of Play I would say the only way is to have some flag (usually in the database) the "father" job can check and block itself in a loop waiting for it.

For exmaple, something like:

```
//take it as an idea, not as working code as it may have typos and dragons
public void doJob() { 
       String uuid = generateUUID();
       List<Employee> empList = Employee.find("long and boring SQL :)").fetch(); 
       for(Employee emp : empList) { 
           //update employee giving uuid so we know this job is related to this parent
           new UpdateEmployeeJob(emp, uuid).now().get(); 
       } 
       int done = 0;
       while(done < empList.size()) {
          //query db for number of instances updated with this uuid 
          //(assuming instance updated once child job is done)
          done = Update.count("uuid = ?1",uuid);
       }
   }
```

That could manage it

Comment: I see what you mean. The downside of doing this would be that no resources are freed while waiting. In fact, additional load is added to the database by checking the UUID field.
When you call await (in a controller), you ask Play to wait for a promised result to be available before resuming your request. While waiting, Play will stop the code, reuse the thread to serve other requests, and resume the code as soon as the promised value you wait for is available".
I guess I could add a Thread.sleep to your while loop to make it less heavy for the DB but I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: I know, it's not perfect, sadly I'm not sure there is an alternative. On the db load this can be managed via Cache, just replace the Updated.count() by a method that checks a value in cache, and if it's not there then it queries the DB and stores the result in cache. You can set the life in cache to be 1 minute so it doesn't query too often.